# React: Wrapping element vs. regular JS Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and really enjoy the Ecosystem. Today I found a webfont loader for React. When used, it looks like this:

```
<WebfontLoader config={config}>
    <App />
</WebfontLoader>
```

What is the advantage of implementing it as a React component vs. just as a regular JS Library that is used as Part of the application? Is this the "React Way" to do things?

I see the need when using context (Like in Redux Provider), but otherwise, I am not sure.

Edit: By "Regular JS Library" I am referring to including a file in the build that waits for DOM ready and then just calls a webfont loader directly, without using a wrapping element in React.

Comment: how will you implement it as a regular JSLibrary? what do you mean with that?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri I've updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Okay! there's no limitation in react for using third party libraries. The Pro for implementing it as a react component is that you have full control of the rendering of the component because the components lifecycles. If you include it as external you'll have to carry about all of this by yourself.